# Improve handling of slow external sources with ImageResizer RemoteReader

Tags: imageresizer

We're using ImageResizer to process and resize images from some customer sites on their way to end users. For the most part, this works really well, and we're pretty happy. The issue that we've been struggling with a little bit lately is that a couple of the remote sources are really, really slow. This isn't a problem with the product, but we'd love some advice on how to use it more effectively to deal with this situation.

The RemoteReader plugin has a (hardcoded) timeout of 15 seconds to read a remote image. Most of the time, that's plenty. If the image is successfully fetched, it's cached on our web server and a CDN, and repeated requests should be quite fast. But if the request times out, the thrown exception returns a 500, and there's nothing (AFAIK) on our web server to remember this. The CDN should cache the error response for some period of time, but generally repeated requests will keep spinning up these attempts to download the image, which will continue to time out.

What's worse, with the biggest culprit, is that the request would eventually succeed, but we're seeing times of several minutes to download what are (in any absolute sense) not very big images. Obviously, we don't want to make users wait that long, but if we could get that image into the local cache, then the downstream requests would work great.

I'm not sure how much control we can exert over any of this behavior without forking the plugin. But if there are best practices we're missing, I'd love to fix that.

Is there any way that we can rate-limit attempts to load remote images that fail?

Is there any way to allow asynchronous transfers from remote sources?

Is there any API for injecting content into the DiskCache if we were to try to build such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way that we can rate-limit attempts to load remote images that fail?

Not in ImageResizer, but there is IIS middleware that can do this (I think) (it's a generic HTTP thing; block URLs if they 500 more than the rate limit).

> Is there any way to allow asynchronous transfers from remote sources?

We offer an async HttpModule, but I think you mean background transfer? You can do this by scheduling a cron task or just making HTTP requests to the server to make the image source be fetching and cached.

> Is there any API for injecting content into the DiskCache if we were to try to build such a thing?

Are you using SourceDiskCache? This caches original images in the disk cache. There's also a handy base class for building custom disk caches.

> I'm not sure how much control we can exert over any of this behavior without forking the plugin. But if there are best practices we're missing, I'd love to fix that.

Don't be afraid to fork it. Git makes merging pretty painless given how stable the project is at this point. Just check upstream when there are new releases announced.

Comment: Re: async transfers, I'm imagining a system where, say, a request comes in for a remote image, the immediate attempt times out, but a retry with a much longer timeout gets queued for "offline". But that only works if we could then put the bits where the caching system would find them.

Comment: We're actually not using the `SourceDiskCache` right now. That is now top of my list to investigate. Doesn't help the timeout case, but would help the case where many requests come for the same remote images with slightly different parameters.

Comment: You can certainly queue failed requests for offline processing, but you may have to add an event hook or something. Most likely a code change would be required.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing would seem to be adding some mechanism to `RemoteReader` to see the exception thrown on timeout. (Or a more general mechanism on all virtual image providers?)

The only way to get content into the `CustomDiskCache` seems to be to actually request a thing from it that misses… and there's enough locking and coordination in there that I don't think I'd want to try refactoring that code to add such a thing. (But maybe I could define some kind of retry-specific virtual image provider that generates identical cache keys, and does its own HTTP requests?)

Comment: The GetCachedFile() method takes a lambda to write the file if it doesn't exist. Here's how we generate the keyBasis: https://github.com/imazen/resizer/blob/0bdde420799f16a10ec61b7ef4509543aa87da76/Core/HttpModuleRequestAssistant.cs#L128-L132